# vsftpd installation not working on virtual server as of 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ftp, amazon-ec2, vsftpd

The process I have used for installing vsftpd since 12.04 no longer works. I get the error `stop: Unknown instance` when restarting the service. I believe this means the configuration is wrong, but I cannot track down the issue. I'm having this problem on a virtual server.

Additionally, running `sudo vsftpd` results in `500 OOPS: munmap` as noted by @Beltran.

---

1. Acquire root privileges

   ```
   sudo -s
   ```
2. Install vsftpd and libpam-pwdfile

   ```
   apt-get install vsftpd libpam-pwdfile
   ```
3. Edit vsftpd.conf

   ```
   mv /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.bak
   vim /etc/vsftpd.conf
   ```

   Copy and paste the following lines.

   ```
   allow_writeable_chroot=YES
   anonymous_enable=NO
   chroot_list_enable=YES
   chroot_local_user=YES
   guest_enable=YES
   guest_username=vsftpd
   hide_ids=YES
   listen=YES
   local_enable=YES
   local_umask=022
   local_root=/var/clients/$USER
   nopriv_user=vsftpd
   pasv_address=127.0.0.1
   pasv_enable=YES
   pasv_min_port=65000
   pasv_max_port=65100
   port_enable=YES
   user_sub_token=$USER
   seccomp_sandbox=NO
   virtual_use_local_privs=YES
   write_enable=YES
   ```
4. Register virtual admin

   ```
   apt-get install apache2-utils
   mkdir /etc/vsftpd
   htpasswd -cd /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd admin
   vim /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
   ```

   Add 1 line for the admin user

   ```
   admin
   ```
5. Configure PAM

   ```
   mv /etc/pam.d/vsftpd /etc/pam.d/vsftpd.bak
   vim /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
   ```

   Copy and paste these 2 lines.

   ```
   auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd
   account required pam_permit.so
   ```
6. Create a local user without shell access

   ```
   useradd --home /home/vsftpd --gid nogroup -m --shell /bin/false vsftpd
   ```
7. Create root directory and give local user proper access.

   ```
   mkdir /var/clients
   chmod -R 755 /var/clients
   chown -R vsftpd:nogroup /var/clients
   ```
8. Register jailed virtual users *(initially, I skip this step)*

   ```
   htpasswd -d /etc/vsftpd/ftpd.passwd {user_name}
   mkdir /var/clients/{user_name}
   ```
9. Restart service

   ```
   service vsftpd restart
   ```

Comment: I have the same issue but using the standard vsftpd configuration:

    $ sudo vsftpd
    500 OOPS: munmap

Comment: This appears to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1219857).

Comment: @roydukkey It looks like the patched fix has been uploaded to trusty-proposed.

Comment: Is it on a virtualized server? See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1313450

Comment: Yes. You're correct. It is on a virtualised server. I just had time to try the configuration, I outline above, a few weeks ago. And, the issue still existed at that point. I'd not thought to update this post.

Comment: This bug fixed in Linux kernel 3.15.8!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're receiving this issue on an AWS EC2 instance, you should try creating the instance with **HVM virtualization** instead of the Paravirtual.

If you still desire a paravirtual instance, there no telling when the bug will be fixed as it is a bug in the Xen kernal, which is used to run virtualization for AWS.

Here is the bug thread addressing this issue in more detail:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1313450

Comment: FYI The fix was released

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 14.04 uses [user sessions](http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/upstart-user-sessions-in-ubuntu-raring.html) which was absent in 12.04, so `service` is looking at the user session, not the system session, and your user isn't running vstfpd(root is). So, you will need to specify `--system` when you use `service` to start, stop or check the status of a service.

vsftpd is a soft-link to upstart, so you won't be able to run it as an unprivileged user, you will need to be root to start or stop or check the status of such a process.

Doing an `ls -l on /etc/init.d/vsftpd` reveals:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 16  2013 /etc/init.d/vsftpd -> /lib/init/upstart-job*
```

which is similar to `cron`, `resolvconf` and a few more, which are all upstart jobs and need to be root to be started or stopped.

> Upstart is an event-based replacement for the /sbin/init daemon which handles starting of tasks and services during boot, stopping them during shutdown and supervising them while the system is running.

These services are usually started on boot. See here for more on upstart:

- [What is upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083/what-is-upstart)

Refer man page of upstart if you want even more!

So, long story short, to start, stop, check status, you need to be root. You can do that as follows:

```
sudo service vsftpd {start|stop|status|restart}
```

and enter your password or use:

```
service vsftpd {start|stop|status|restart} --system
```

Comment: That's all true. I've been starting the service from root. Also, the permissions on `/etc/init.d/vsftpd` are as you suggest.

Comment: @roydukkey: So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: A reason why the same exact configuration doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04, but does on 12.04-13.10.

Comment: @roydukkey: Are you sure you don't need to use `sudo` even on 13.04? I doubt that.

Comment: @roydukkey: Edited my answer why the change in 14.04 and also added steps to avoid being root for this purpose. Hope this helps and is what you were looking for.

Comment: Before beginning my vsftpd configuration I do acquire root. I guess I figured this was intuitive enough that I didn't include it in my instructions, but I guess I should add it.

Comment: I found this in a log at `/var/log/upstart/vsftpd.log.1.gz`: `/etc/vsftpd.conf: listen disabled - service will not start; vsftpd stop/pre-start, process 1880`. What can you make of that?

Comment: @roydukkey: You have set `listen=YES` in your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, can you double check that if it is really set to `YES` and what is the output of `ps aux | grep vsftpd`?

Comment: `listen` is set to `YES`.

Comment: What do you get when you do `sudo service vsftpd start`?

Comment: `ps aux | grep vsftpd` outputs `ubuntu    9669  0.0  0.0  10464   916 pts/0    S+   15:32   0:00 grep --color=auto vsftpd(red)`

Comment: `sudo service vsftpd start` results in `vsftpd start/pre-start, process 9689`

Comment: I might have the same problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/457248/vsftpd-not-working

Comment: horse shit, ls -l on my machine reveals "no such file or directory"

Comment: @r3wt: ls -l shouldn't return anything if there are no files in the directory. Please verify what command you are executing and weather the output is what you have posted.

Comment: @io8in i ctrl + c && ctrl + v exactly what you typed

Answer (score 3):

Enable trusty-proposed in your software sources and re-install vsftpd. I'm checking if this passes muster.

If you don't wish to enable proposed in your sources vsftpd source and builds are available on this page. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/vsftpd/3.0.2-1ubuntu2.14.04.1

Comment: I don't really want to do this for the entire server as it will be production. Is there a way to just update vsftpd from trust-proposed?

Comment: @roydukkey, you can enable it, `apt-get update` then `apt-get install vsftpd` it will update only vsftpd and its required dependencies (it will ask for confirmation, check change list). Then disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Still new to Ubuntu. Had it working on Ubuntu 12.4 with no hassles but on Ubuntu 14.04, this is what i did:

in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file add these 2 lines:

```
allow_writeable_chroot = YES
seccomp_sandbox = NO
```

Change the value of `pam_service_name` to `ftp`.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Ifthe user is jailed within `/var/www/html/kofi_site` directory then simply run:

`sudo chmod ugo-w /var/www/html/kofi_site`

Comment: This worked for me, any reason for the downvote?

Comment: I would *guess* it was downvoted because it didn't address the problem the OP was having. If the question had been "What do I do if the user is jailed within the /var/www/html/kofi_site directory?" I would assume you would have gotten better results.