# VSFTPD not working

Tags: ftp, amazon-ec2, vsftpd

I followed [instructions](http://blog.liwen.name/configure-vsftpd-on-amazon-ec2/148) and [other instructions](http://unixsystems.blogspot.se/2012/09/setting-up-amazon-aws-ec2-ftp-server.html) too but because it is not user-friendly, the ftp server is not working.

```
# This option specifies the location of the RSA key to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
#user ddns address
pasv_address=54.... (my ip)
#choose and range you like
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
```

Then:

```
~$ sudo service vsftpd status
vsftpd stop/waiting
ubuntu@ip:~$ sudo service vsftpd restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
vsftpd start/pre-start, process 9711
```

But it can not connect with an ftp client. I opened the ports in security group and reinstalled everything, still not working. What can be done? What can't it work per default? I try to connect with a user account that I added with `useradd`.

```
$ sudo vsftpd
500 OOPS: munmap

$ service vsftpd begin
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service vsftpd begin

The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but begin is not supported for Upstart jobs.
```

Comment: This appears to be the [same issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453784/vsftpd-installation-not-working-as-of-14-04) I'm having. Still no solution though.

Comment: @roydukkey I gave up and switched to proftpd and that works.

Comment: What instruction did you use?

Comment: @roydukkey It was easy. `apt-get install proftpd` and then some edit to the `.conf` file and then the ftp server works. I hope you too can get it running.

Answer (score 3):

You've already answered your own question, but I'll go ahead and put this here for others who've come here.

Use `proftpd`, as @Programmer-400 mentioned, and don't bother trying to resolve the vsftpd.  I looked into it and it seems that for ubuntu 14.04, there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1313450) somewhere deep in some related library, which hasn't been resolved yet.

`apt-get install proftpd`

Installed without issue, also uninstallting `vsftpd` along the way.  Configuration is just as simple.

http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-proftpd-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/