# What was the behavior before modern init replacements?

Tags: usb, upstart, init, history-of-ubuntu

Based on this excellent answer on changes to init daemons: [What is Upstart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083/what-is-upstart)

...it seems like modern init replacements including upstart and systemd have added functionality because they are event driven etc. The common example that is given is the one using a USB stick as described here.

> - The addition or removal of USB flash drives and other portable storage / network devices while the machine is running
> - The discovery and scanning of new storage devices, without locking the system, especially when a disk may not even power on until it is
>     scanned
> - The loading of firmware for a device, which may need to occur after it is detected but before it is usable
>
> Upstart's event-driven model allows it to respond to events
>   asynchronously as they are generated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart

My question is for example what was exactly the difference in behavior when inserting a USB stick and using the traditional System V init. What had to be done?

Since it provides advantages with loading firmware - does this relates to, does part of the job or replaces need for drivers for peripherals?

Comment: I wouldn't call systemd "event-driven", exactly. It is dependency-driven, units and services are started as and when something needs them.